# How can I add a new line to an already existing section in a .ini file, with batch commands?

Tags: batch-file, command, echo, ini

I have a file *MyFile.ini* with a section in it *[MySection]*

I want to add a new line with a return after it under that section, via a batch file.

Here's the batch file I last tried:

```
@echo off
Set file=MyFile.ini
Set section=[MySection]
Set newline=MyNewValue=MyNewSetting

for /f "tokens=*" %%l in (%file%) do (
(echo %%l)>> "%file%"

if /i "%%l"=="%section%" (
(echo %newline%)>> "%file%"
) 
)

exit
```

The above has no effect on the ini file.

I want the ini file to go from this:

```
[MySection]
SomeExistingValue=SomeExistingSetting
```

To this:

```
[MySection]
SomeExistingValue=SomeExistingSetting
MyNewValue=MyNewSetting
```

Any answer will be greatly appreciated because once I can figure this out I can replicate it and add several settings to my file, it's all a bit tedious doing it manually, especially when I do the exact same thing to the exact same file, every time. The file name never changes, the section always exists, the setting I am adding never exists, so all that stuff does not need to be accounted for, nor does making a backup of the file, I can just unzip my backed up file if it gets messed up.

Comment: If there are multiple sections in your file, or `[MySection]` isn't the last section of the`.ini` file, then I would strongly advise you to forget about a batch file. Choose something more suited to editing files, batch files are for running a series of basic commands.

Comment: If it only exists once, on one line, why would it be a problem?

Comment: I didn't say it couldn't be done, just that you're using the wrong tool for the job. _If it wasn't a problem, you wouldn't be on here asking for help with it_. Generally, the sections in an `.ini` file, do not need to be in a specific order. So my advice, if you want an easy to understand generic/reusable method would be to insert your line directly beneath the section name line, _instead of adding it one or two lines above whatever the next section is, if one even exists_.

Comment: All it needs to do is find the line with [MySection] on the line, do the equivalent of hit enter after it, then add the new line. I might have a look at doing it with AutoIt3. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example based upon my commented methodology:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "file=MyFile.ini"
Set "section=[MySection]"
Set "newline=MyNewValue=MyNewSetting"

Copy /Y "%file%" "%file%.bak">NUL 2>&1||Exit /B 1
(For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=]" %%G In (
        '^""%__AppDir__%find.exe" /N /V ""^<"%file%.bak"^"'
    )Do If /I "%%H"=="%section%" (Echo=%%H
        Echo %newline%)Else Echo=%%H)>"%file%"

Rem Del "%file%.bak"
```

I have `Rem`arked the last line, because I think it's more important to ensure that the resultant file, `%file%`, is correct, before you `Del`ete the original, `%file%.bak`. The choice to do so ultimately lies with yourself.